# Create a 3 channel Bitmap with C#?

Tags: c#, image, drawing, gdi+

I'm creating a bunch of random images for testing and I'm using a third party tool to load the images and output a video.  When it loads the bmps create using C# it's throwing an exception that the images need to be 3 channel.

I'm new to the image manipulation world, how would I make a standard .bmp file created using C# a 3 channel image?

```
  //bitmap
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

Comment: Well, `ARGB` has four channels: red, green, blue and alpha. Perhaps you could try `Format24bppRgb` which only has the red, green and blue channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're using a four-channel [pixel format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` has a red, green, blue and alpha channel. I would suggest trying a pixel format which has three channels, such as `PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb`.